# Easiest way to ensure that two dependent form fields are both filled?

Tags: html

I'm doing a little asp.net projet where I am doign a data filtering service.

I my very big input form, I have two fields that are dependent of each other.

It is two "number" input fields that allow the user to pick a "from" and "to" pricepoint from which the application returns all instances with prices in that range.

the two input elements look like this:

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    
                                <input name="recPriceLow" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="From price"> 
                                </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                                                                        
                                <input name="recPriceTop" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="To price"> 
                                </div>                    

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Now my issue is that I only want users to be able to push the "submit" button if both the "from" and "to" field has been filled, because that's the only thing that makes sense.

Can I encode this requirement easily somehow?

Comment: You can set conditions using javascript while submitting the form or can set a new attribute "required" to input the tag.

Comment: Example -  <input required name="recPriceLow" type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="From price"/>

Comment: hm, yeah, the js solution is probably the most viable, I don't see how to solution with "required" creates the conditional behaviour I need

Comment: when you add the required attribute to your input & submit the form you get a  message in the form field

Comment: yes, this would require the user to fill out the fields. But this is not what I want. I would like to only be required to fill out input field recPriceTop, if recPriceLow has already been fileld

Comment: Ok, so then JS will solve your problem easily.